# How do I access My GRails Views pages in Browser

Tags: grails-2.3

In GRails My views page locations are in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF\grails-app\views\index.gsp

I used tomcat 7.0 server I deployed my application as .war extension in webapps

When I try to access my index.gsp page from browser

(URL is: localhost:8080/myapp/index.gsp)

it is showing the following error

HTTP Status 404 - "/index.gsp" not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your urlMapping.groovy, it should be

"/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')

if this is same than hit just  localhost:8080/myapp
it should work

Comment: In my project there no urlMapping.groovy file, tell me the default location of that file

Comment: graails-app/config/urlMapping.groovy